# Can not set theme/style in FragmentDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

```
class BottomBarFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

      override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val contextThemeWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_BaseDarkTheme)
            val localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper)
            binding = FragmentBottomBarBinding.inflate(localInflater, container, false)
            // tried setStyle also
            setStyle(0, R.style.Theme_BaseDarkTheme)
        }

}
```

style

```
<style name="Theme.BaseDarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="dividerColor">@color/divider_dark</item>
</style>
```

in fragment dialog layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/llParent"
        android:background="?attr/dividerColor"
        >
```

According to this, my layout should be dark, but it is light always. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`setStyle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#setStyle(int,%20int)) says this:

> Call to customize the basic appearance and behavior of the fragment's
>   dialog. This can be used for some common dialog behaviors, taking care
>   of selecting flags, theme, and other options for you. The same effect
>   can be achieve by manually setting Dialog and Window attributes
>   yourself. **Calling this after the fragment's Dialog is created will
>   have no effect.**

Fragment's Dialog will be created after `onCreate()` and before `onCreateView()`. 
Try calling `setStyle()` from the `onCreate()` method

Comment: have you declared  ` <attr name="dividerColor" format="reference" />` in attrs.xml ?

Comment: <attr name="dividerColor" format="reference|color" />

Comment: I have created this, and thing is, it is working in Activity, Fragment, but not bottom sheet fragment

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, if you are trying to use something, what have "dialog" in name, you should build dialog. To do this, there is one method like onCreateDialog().

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),your_style);

    ...

    return builder.create();
}
```

Otherwise, you should extend just a Fragment, and there you can call in onCreateView() something like this:

```
Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),your_style);
    LayoutInflater newInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    View view = newInflater.inflate(your_layout,container,false);
```

Sorry for java code, but there should be similar code.